# Power Query (M) _ Dynamically update a column list for List.Sum function

Tags: excel, list, powerquery, m

I'm not sure if even possible but the goal is to dynamically update a query based on the user selecting a date. I have a table in my Excel file while updates a value which feeds to PeriodString variable (below)

```
/*Parameter name = PeriodString */
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PeriodString"]}[Content],
    StrPeriod = Source[Value]{0}
in
    StrPeriod
```

The part of the code I want to update is the [ ..months selected ].

```
=List.Sum({[FYOpening],[January],[February],[March],[April],[May]})
```

With the below variable

```
=List.Sum({PeriodStr})
```

I tried using Table.Column as I realize I have to convert the value to a list of selectable columns but I cant' get it to work.

```
=List.Sum({Table.Column(PeriodString{0},PeriodString[0])})

Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "[FY Opening],[Januar..." to type List.
Details:
    Value=[FY Opening],[January],[February],[March],[April],[May]
    Type=[Type]
```

Let me know if possible / alternatives.

Comment: Your months are all separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly value like **"[Col1],[Col2],[Col3]"** for PeriodString, then use such code:

```
let
    Source = #table({"a".."e"},{{1..5}, {6..10}}),
    PeriodString = "[b],[d],[e]",
    sum = Table.AddColumn(Source, "sum", each List.Sum(Expression.Evaluate("{"&PeriodString&"}", [_=_])))
in
    sum
```

I'd prefer to use PQ list instead:

```
let
    Source = #table({"a".."e"},{{1..5}, {6..10}}),
    list = {"b","d","e"},
    sum = Table.AddColumn(Source, "sum", each List.Sum(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_, list))))
in
    sum
```